# iOS add notification to the lockscreen that will not disappear

Tags: iphone, ios5, push-notification

is it possible to add a notification to the lockscreen that will not disappear?

---

or (my second choice)

Is it possible to add a notification to the lockscreen, which will be thre until the iPhone is unlocked the next time?

For example:

- iPhone is unlocked
- message incoming
- lock iPhone
- message is in lockscreen
- unlock iPhone
- message is not longer in lockscreen

---

Edit:

My goal is to have a notification on the lockscreen every time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in ios5 there is a new feature in notification that notifications are automatically shown in the lockscreen if the user select the option from the setting but your app cannot receive any notification if your app in foreground.

Comment: Okay... is it possible with this option that the notification is always in the lockscreen? I could add a notification when the view will disappear.

Comment: can you explain the meaning of "view" here. because i am talking about the app not a single view of app

Comment: My app is a single view application, so if the user presses the homebutton the app and the view will disappear. At this point i could add a notification, right?

Comment: one min add a notification what?
you cannnot send a notification from your app to device.

Comment: it´s not possible to add a local notification? the calendar app can do it too.

Comment: thats was alerm not a notification.

Comment: okay, i never heard "alerm" before... but i can use these alerms to add a "notification" to the lockscreen ?

Comment: @Maik639: Apple apps can do things that you cannot do in your app. For example, if you set a calendar event with a reminder say 1 hour in advance. The reminder goes off while the screen is off. 10 minutes later you press the screen lock button, the screen lights and tells you that the event is due in 50 minutes instead of 60 as when the notification was delivered. This is something no non-Apple app can do.

Answer (score 1):

No, neither is possible. If your app is in foreground, it gets delivered to your app directly and is not displayed. If the screen is locked or you app is in background, the notification is shown.